# Gitbook TOC Numbering discrepancy

Tags: tableofcontents, gitbook

When I use the gitbook editor's preview server, the numbering for the TOC is what I expect:

1. First Chapter
   1.1 Sub-section

   - 1.1.1. Sub-sub section
   - 1.1.2. Second sub section
2. Second Chapter
   2.1 Sub-section

When using command line gitbook to generate html, the result is different, and clearly incorrect:

1. First Chapter
   1.2 Sub-section

   - 1.2.3 Sub-sub section
   - 1.2.4 Second sub section
2. Second Chapter
   2.3 Sub-section

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong or how to correct it? Thank you!

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: how can you solve this ? because I encountered the same issue here :(

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I think you need to prefix the subchapter lines with two dots:

```
..* Subchapter
```